# Can I authenticate on jconsole using kerberos?

Tags: java, authentication, jmx, kerberos, jconsole

Does anyone know if it's possible to authenticate on jconsole using kerberos?
I set up a tomcat with kerberos authentication which works fine if you visit the manager in a browser. The trouble starts when trying to connect to the jmx port as jconsole doesn't seem to pass the client's kerberos ticket. If anyone could give me any pointers, would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Ed.

Comment: Did you try connecting jconsole with command prompt by placing Kerberos path in classpath?

Answer (score 0):

I might have misunderstood your question but have you configured the JMX connector or just the web application to use Kerberos?

There is a [Krb5LoginModule](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/security/jaas/spec/com/sun/security/auth/module/Krb5LoginModule.html) which you can specify using the [com.sun.management.jmxremote.login.config](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/agent.html#PasswordAccessFiles) property to enable Kerberos for the JMX connector.